Question About the Proof of Proposition 6.1.3 of Cohn's Measure Theory
I couldn't fully understand the following proof and I marked the two steps where I was stuck with 'why'. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could check them. Thanks in advance.
$\textbf{Proposition 6.1.3}$ Let $T$: $\mathbb{R}^d$ $\to$ $\mathbb{R}^d$ be an invertible linear map. Then $\lambda(T(B)) = |det(T)|\lambda(B)$ holds for each Borel subset $B$ of $\mathbb{R}^d$.
$\textbf{Proof}$ The maps $T$ and $T^{-1}$ are continuous and hence measurable wih respect to $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$; thus $T(B)$ is a Borel set if and only if $B$ is a Borel set.
Since $T$ is invertible, there exist linear maps $T_1, T_2, \dots, T_n$ such that $T={T_1}\circ{T_2}\circ\dots\circ{T_n}$ and such that each $T_k$ operates on a vector $x$ in one of the following ways:
(a) one component of $x$ is multiplied by a nonzero number, and the other components are left unchanged;
(b) two components of $x$ are interchanged, and the other components are left unchanged;
(c) for some $i$ and $j$ the component $x_i$ is replaced with $x_i+x_j$, while the other components of $x$ are left unchanged.
In view of the relation $det(T) = det(T_1)det(T_2)\dots det(T_n)$, it sufficed to show that $\lambda(T_k(B)) = |det(T_k)|\lambda(B)$ holds for each $k$ and each Borel set $B$.
First suppose that $T_k$ arises through case(a) or case(b) above. Then it is easy to check that $\lambda(T_k(B)) = |det(T_k)|\lambda(B)$ holds if $B$ is a cube with edges parallel to the coordinate axes ($\textbf{Why?}$) and hence if $B$ is an open set or an arbitrary Borel set (use the regularity of $\lambda$).
Next suppose that $T_k$ arises through case (c). Then there exist indices $i$ and $j$ such that if $x=(x_1,\dots, x_d)$, then the $i$th component of $T_k(x)$ is $x_i+x_j$, while the other components of $T_k(x)$ agree with the corresponding components of $x$. Let us view $\mathbb{R}^d$ as the product of $\mathbb{R}$ (corresponding to the $i$th coordinate in $\mathbb{R}^d$) with $\mathbb{R}^{d-1}$ (corresponding to the remaining coordinates). Let $B$ be a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}$. It is easy to check that for each $u$ in $\mathbb{R}^{d-1}$ the sections at $u$ of $B$ and of $T_k(B)$ are translates of one another ($\textbf{Why?}$) and hence have the same Lebesgue measure. Thus it follows from the theory of product measures that $\lambda(B) = \lambda(T_k(B))$. Since $det(T_k)=1$ holds whenever $T_k$ arises through case (c), the proof is complete.

Have you tried to make the checks yourself? When someone writes that it really does mean that if you try to prove that small sub-claim yourself you will indeed find that it’s easy and after the fact realise that it probably doesn’t need to be spelled out further.

Perhaps the question I posted is very simple for you. However, as a beginner in mathematics, some steps are not so obvious to me. I spent more than an hour carefully writing down this question in not-so-proficient LaTeX because I also hope that people with the same confusion in the future can be inspired here, just as I have been inspired many times by other people's questions and discussions in this forum.

Sorry, I didn’t mean to actually say that it would be easy to figure out but mainly that after you had figured it out you would probably agree that it was ok not to spell out the details. So it was kind of a genuine question ie have you actually tried to take it as an exercise and figure out a proof yourself? (Because that it was what the writer expects, he doesn’t expect you to think it’s obvious or immediate)

For the first (why?) it follows from interpreting the absolute valued of the determinant for a linear map on $R^{n}$ geometrically. The absolute value of the determinant is how much the volume of a unit cube will be scaled by. You can see this by picking the standard basis and considering the matrix representation in this basis. The columns are the image of the sides of the unit cube and the determinant is its volume.
In general, I think the easier way to see this claim is to recall the cubes generate the Borel sigma algebra. Since we are dealing with Borel sets, it is enough to think about what would happen to their generators. In $R^{n}$ since the cubes generate the Borel sets, we can consider what happens when an invertible linear map acts on a cube - it scales its volume (since it has nonzero determinant). So the result we want holds for cubes.
Since it holds for cubes, we can then extend the properties to the rest of the Borel sets in the usual way - by showing the subsets of $R^{n}$ that has this property is a sigma algebra. Since it contains the cubes, then it contains the Borel sets and thus the Borel sets have this property.

Thanks a lot! I understand now.
